# React Router - Pass chosen component to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following in App.js;

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
        </div>
    )
}
```

And in Navbar.js

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <nav className="Navbar">
                    <ul className="Navbar-list">
                        <li className="Navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/register" className="Navbar-link">Sign Up</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="Navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/login" className="Navbar-link">Log In</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/register">
                        <RegisterForm />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/login">
                        <LoginForm />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

This works fine, but shouldn't my RegisterForm and LoginForm components be passed to App? I would have thought the display of the page should be determined within App, but at the moment, it's being determined by the navbar component.

Comment: If you want you can wrap your `.App` in `Router` and put the `Switch` there instead of in `Navbar`. It's just better refactoring.

Comment: @vatz88 Ah, I never thought of that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement that the link to the nav item is in the same component as the matching route. The current page is stored by the browser history, and accessible 'globally'.

**You are free to move the content into the app component** directly, which is arguably more correct semantically, as you observed:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Navbar />

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/register">
                        <RegisterForm />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/login">
                        <LoginForm />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="Navbar">
                <ul className="Navbar-list">
                    <li className="Navbar-item">
                        <Link to="/register" className="Navbar-link">Sign Up</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="Navbar-item">
                        <Link to="/login" className="Navbar-link">Log In</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Note I did edit your post as <Navbar /> needs to be within <Router> tags as it contains the Links, but that's exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like this?

```
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
              <Navbar />

             <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterForm} />
               <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
             </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
      )
```

Navbar.js

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="Navbar">
                <ul className="Navbar-list">
                  <li className="Navbar-item">
                   <Link to="/register" className="Navbar-link">Sign Up</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="Navbar-item">
                   <Link to="/login" className="Navbar-link">Log In</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```